# What did a npm audit fix --force change and how do you fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm, apn, node-forge

I was trying to `npm install apn --save` and used `npm audit fix --force`.  The 'Hope you know what you are doing' message made me realize that I dont know what I am doing.  After that I originally was getting

```
node /home/ec2-user/myapp/bin/www: symbol lookup error: 
/home/ec2-user/myapp/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: undefined symbol: napi_add_finalizer
```

so I updated node to `V14.16.0` but that didn't help so I decided to delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and ran `npm install`  after.
This error would now come up,

```
PM2 error: Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

and I realized that PM2 didnt use the new node version. I upgraded PM2 and now it shows that my app is `online` opposed to `errored`.
But I still get a 502 error if my node server was running(port 8080) when trying to run my website

```
[proxy_http:error] [pid 22860] (20014)Internal error 
(specific information not available): [client my IP address]
 AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8080
```

and a 503 error if I stopped my node server.

```
[proxy:error] [pid 13022] (111)Connection refused:
 AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Any and all help would be much appreciated. Also I believe `node-forge` was a dependent for `apn` and needed the `npm audit fix -- force`

Answer (score 39):

`npm audit` is a utility that reads your `package.json` and checks the version of it's dependencies against a security vulnerability database. When something is found it gives you the severity of vulnerability and the option to `fix` it.

What the fixing does is upgrade the unsafe dependencies of your project. `npm audit fix` only modifies the dependencies that shouldn't cause problems based on [SEMVER](https://semver.org/) rules.

The `--force` is a dangerious option because it upgrades the dependencies regardless of any rules. This can cause a dependency to go from version `1.2.0` to version `2.3.0`, for example. That means that functions that you use in your project may not exist anymore or have a different behaviour effectively breaking your application.

One option to fix this issue is going back on your versioning system (git, cvs, etc.) and recover the previous `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. Then you should delete `node_module` and any npm cache and run `npm install`.

More info on `npm audit` can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and lots of information. I can see why it's important to have a versioning system, unfortunately I was just mainly backing up the app, routes, and view files. It sounds like everyone can have different problems here, sorry I'm not much help there. With a --force fix does it upgrade every dependency or just the ones that the audit suggests?

Comment: It will upgrade just the suggested dependencies. If you can't determine which ones got upgraded, as a last resort you can change the dependencies on your `package.json`  one by one to use major versions (e.g 2.0.0, 3.0.0, ...) and run `npm install` after each change to see if it works. Personally I would start with client-facing (parsers, file handling, webservers), cryptography or framework dependencies as people look for vulnerabilities more often on them.

Comment: It is my understanding that  `npm install apn`   added one dependency    "apn": "^2.2.0"  to my `package.json`  and 3 packages to `package-lock.json`     notably ` "node-forge": { "version": "0.7.6" `  . The npm audit report suggests that node-forge <= 0.9.2  is a high severity and that a  `npm audit fix --force ` will fix it. Not wanting to use that again I `npm uninstall apn`  and with it went any reference to apn or node-forge.   I understand that if I was using that code anywhere during a `force` I could expect it to break, but  I only had that code after doing the inital apn install.